# Question regarding time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, inertial-frames, observers, time-dilation

if people in semi-light-speed ships age slower, does the world appeared to those people also 'age slower'? Because it is the external world which is moving at semi-light-speed to the people in the space ship. But the external world should appear to 'age faster' since when the people on the space ship return to earth, the people on the earth aged more, right? What's wrong?

Comment: Every  clock runs fastest in its own frame.

Answer (score 1):

Time dilation is indeed symmetric, since velocity is relative. But if a rocket ship turns around, it's definition of simultaneity changes, and it has to take that into account when calculating the ages of people on Earth.

Something very similar happens with lengths in ordinary Euclidean space, except that the lengths are longer rather than shorter. The picture below illustrates it well.
[image: Euclidean twin paradox]

(Image by Ben Rudiak-Gould, from Wikipedia.)

Comment: So there is an *asymmetry* between the worldlines of Jack and Jill.

Comment: Eric, I found what I was looking for. See my answer below.

Comment: @foolishmuse I think the image I reposted explains the spatial analog of the twin paradox well. Jack thinks Jill's distance is increasing faster than his, and vice versa, and yet Jill really does have a longer path because she turned.

Comment: In any experiment it is wise to get rid of any extraneous factors which might confuse the situation. So in this experiment get rid of the difference in distance traveled. And get rid of any aspect of turning around. Simply have the twins travel in a straight line, one at a fast speed and one at a slow speed. The one who traveled at a fast speed will always be younger. Now imagine that either twin can claim that they remained stationary. And only the other twin moved. This brings the experiment down to the only critical factors involved.

Comment: As long as they are moving uniformly, either twin can regard themselves at rest. That's the principle of relativity and dates back to Galileo. No experiment you can perform will reveal which twin is "really" moving (or "moving faster", if you prefer), and hence the question of "which twin is younger" has only relative answers. If either twin turns around to meet the other, then that twin will end up being younger when they meet up. The results of any experiment may be analyzed in any inertial frame, so picking one special one is what's really extraneous.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there are several synchronized clocks in the Earth's frame along the ship's path. Each time that the ship passes by one of that clocks, the difference with respect to the clock inside the ship increases. The clock in the ship shows less time.

So, in this sense, the world (meaning Earth's frame) seems 'to age faster' compared to the ship's frame.

But, suppose that instead of only one ship, there are a convoy of ships, each of them with a synchronized clock in the ship's frame. And an observer Bob in the Earth (or anywhere at the ship's path, but static with respect to the Earth). This observer will also note that each time a new ship comes close, when comparing the clocks, it is the clock of the ship that shows bigger and bigger time compared with Bob's clock.

The comparison for time dilation is always between an observer with his clock (proper time), and a row of clocks of another frame (coordinate time).

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the problem of the "twin paradox". It seems at first that there should be no difference between the observers on earth and those on the ship since there is symmetry between the two frames, however, this symmetry is only apparent because the spaceship makes a return trip, i.e. it accelerates and breaks the symmetry of the problem. The accelerated frame of reference of the ship makes it obvious who the real travelers were, the motion is not simply relative between the two. Thus, the travelers on the ship have experienced time dilation and appear younger than the observers who stayed on Earth. It is important to remember that to apply the Lorentz transformation between frames, the frames must be *inertial*. Non-inertial frames like those of rotating systems and spaceships that accelerate, decelerate and come back home are not frames to which one may calculate a boost.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you know that my clock currently says 3:00PM.  Does that tell how anything about how fast it ticks?  Answer:  Of course not.  No matter how fast or slow my clock runs, I can always set it to any time at all.

So:  Just as you pass me, I say "My clock says 5PM, your clock says 3PM, and yours is ticking slower than mine."  And you say "My clock says 3PM, yours says 5PM, and yours is ticking slower than mine."

Each of us has a perfectly consistent story to tell.

Answer (score 0):

In SR, if two people are moving relative to each other at constant velocity,  each person will be equally time dilated in the frame of the other person. In those circumstances, the movements of the people, and the effects of SR, are entirely symmetrical.

However, if you have an unsymmetrical set-up in which one person moves at a constant velocity and the other person moves away from them, turns around and comes back to them, then the person who covers the greater distance along a route which includes periods of acceleration will age less than the person moving at constant velocity.

So, you need to make sure you don't confuse the two set-ups.

Answer (score -3):

Einstein himself answered this question [in his paper here.](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol7-trans/82)   What Einstein said pretty well contradicts with the other answers above.  He says is that you cannot look at special relativity alone.  You must also consider general relativity; that is, you must also consider the gravitational field which encompasses all of space.   He says:

*But, while in the special theory of relativity a portion of space without matter and devoid of an electromagnetic field is truly empty (i.e., not characterized by any physical quantities), it is quite different in general relativity. There, empty space in the previous sense has physical qualities, mathematically characterized by the components of the potential of gravitation that determine the metrical behavior of that portion of space as well as its gravitational field. This situation can very well be interpreted by speaking of an ether whose state varies from point to point. However, one has to be careful not to attribute to this “ether” any matterlike properties (e.g., a distinct velocity at each point).*

And:
*all stars in the universe can be thought of as taking part in the generation of the gravitational field*

Likewise Abramowicz and Bajtlik referred to the “starry sky above” [in their paper here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.2428.pdf)with an answer to the twin paradox *In conclusion, we stress that in all situations in which the absolute motion may be defined in terms of some invariant global properties of the spacetime, the twin who moves faster with respect to the global standard of rest is younger at the reunion.*

So Einstein is rejecting the twin paradox as an issue.  He has recognized that the twin that moves faster through the gravitational field (what A&B describe as a global standard of rest) ages less. Einstein says that one must be careful that any "ether" does not have "matterlike properties".  In my mind this perfectly describes a quantum field.

Comment: I think you need to re-read Einstein's paper. He says nothing to contradict the other answers, and agrees with them that two clocks in *uniform* relative motion will each measure the other to be slower. Only if one turns around is there any possibility of comparing them side by side (as in the twin paradox). Einstein explains that situation using general relativity: in the coordinate system that turns around there arises a "gravitational" force due to acceleration. This is a valid way to consider things, but is overkill.

Comment: @EricSmith your interpretation clearly has absolutely nothing to do with ether. But Einstein very clearly points out that what he's describing has either like qualities. Why would he do that if it had nothing to do with it. Empty space has physical qualities derived from the gravitational field. he has very clearly connected special and general relativity in exactly the way I am describing.

Comment: Einstein's explanation in the body of his paper also has nothing to do with aether. He only brings it up parenthetically at the end of the paper in response to another "question". Also note that he very explicitly disclaims assigning any velocity or any other mechanical property to the aether. His "aether" (spacetime) cannot serve as a frame of reference.

Comment: @EricSmith. His ether is not Spacetime. His ether is the gravitational field. And if you'll notice the way he describes it is exactly the way one would describe any quantum field. As having no velocity or other mechanical properties.